# How to get a count of variables passed to awk

Tags: awk, scripting

I am trying to invoke awk inside a bash script and passing some bash variables values to it. Is there any way to get a count of these variables and print all which are passed to it inside awk.

No. of variables passed to awk would be dynamic.

Below example

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME="Dell"
SERIAL="12345"
echo "Hello" | awk -v a=$NAME -v b=$SERIAL '{ print a,b }'
```

> Referenced, Working example, Irvur's answer in here

```
#!/bin/bash

function confirm_peers (){
  header_def=("${header_def[@]:-None}")
  read -r -p "Enter nodes from header[${header_def[*]}]: " -a header
  header=("${header[@]:-${header_def[@]}}") ;
  echo -e "\nInput Recorded - ${header[@]} \n"
}

createEncConfig()
{
 /usr/bin/awk -f - <<-'EOE' ${header[*]}  FS=":" $1
  BEGIN {
    count=1
    for (i = 1; i < ARGC - 2; ++i) {
    split(ARGV[i], ar, "=");
    print ar[2]
    }
print "\nCount=" ARGC -3
        }
EOE
}
confirm_peers
# Making array content adaptable to awk input
for x in ${!header[@]} ; do header[x]="a=${header[x]}"; done
createEncConfig $1
```

> Referenced - Easiest so far , Kusalananda's answer

```
#!/bin/bash

function confirm_peers (){
  header_def=("${header_def[@]:-None}")
  read -r -p "Enter nodes from header[${header_def[*]}]: " -a header
  header=("${header[@]:-${header_def[@]}}") ;
  echo -e "\nInput Recorded - ${header[@]} \n"
}

createEncConfig()
{
/usr/bin/awk -v args="${header[*]}" -f - <<-'EOE' FS=":" $1
BEGIN {
  count=split(args,ar," ")
  for ( x in ar ) {
    print ar[x]
  }
print "\n" count
}
EOE
}
confirm_peers
createEncConfig $1
```

Output :
Just pass any dummy file

$ `bash /tmp/a.bsh /tmp/enc1.txt`

```
Enter nodes from header[None]: a b c d

Input Recorded - a b c d

a
b
c
d

Count=4
```

Thanks to all ..

Comment: I don't understand why you don't know how many variables you're passing to awk. You're specifically passing two here. Can you show an example where you have an *unknown* number of variables you're passing to awk?

Comment: yes, here I am passing two but it was just for example, now it is like this and seems working,  header is an array holding input from user , this way I am passing dynamic variables. /usr/bin/awk -f - <<-'EOE' $(echo "${header[*]}")  FS=":" $1 .............etc

Comment: then just do `echo ${#header[@]}` everywhere you want, to know how many arguments are there

Comment: I had to read the count inside awk , once I invoke awk inside bash , it doesn't see anything from bash,

Comment: read within `awk`, so `awk '{... ; print args; ....}' args=${#header[@]}`. or if you need values `awk '{... ;split(args, intoArray [, separator]) ; print intoArray[1]; ....}' args="$(echo {header[@]})"`, better to use `printf`

Comment: @sddgob I can't see args inside BEGIN this way

Comment: depending on `awk` implementations shell variables are not available within BEGIN block and you will need convert thrm into awk variables with `-v Var`, while I don't see any point of using it within BEGIN block. you also can do it by `awk  -F'SEP' '{ print NF }' <<<"${header[*]}"` in short that I moved into an answer

Comment: couldn't you just pass an additional variable, ala `-v nargs=${#header[@]}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option I can think of is to reposition those variables so they feature in `ARGV`. `ARGC` will indicate how many of them there are. Beware this makes the variables unavailable in `BEGIN` block. You also need to account for any file names that you may be passing as parameters to `awk` by subtracting the number of such files from `ARGC`

```
echo "Hello" | awk  '{ print a, b, ARGC - 1}' a=$NAME b=$SERIAL
DELL 12345 2
```

Comment: ARGC should help, wondering why awk doesn't consider them as an input file

Comment: @Bharat, good question. `awk` treats anything with a `=` in it as a variable assignment.  The only way to get `awk` to treat it `a=$NAME` as a file appears to be using `--` to signal end of options. For example `echo "Hello" | awk  -- '{ print FILENAME, a, b, ARGC - 1}'  a=$NAME`

Comment: One more thing, ARGV stores complete assignment i.e a=$NAME in it , any easy way to figure out the variable from it, as here  I have hard code a and b but values should be dynamic, echo "Hello" | awk -- '{ print FILENAME, a, b,ARGV[1], ARGC - 1}' a=$NAME

Comment: @Bharat, `split(ARGV[1], a, "="), print a[0],a[1]`

Comment: @iruvar  `--` will **not** prevent `awk` from treating subsequent arguments of the `a=b` form as variable assigments. You can check with `echo | awk -- '{print KEY}' KEY=value`. See also my answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/475013/308316). Your example is misleading because `FILENAME` will be `-` if it's the stdin -- try it with `a=17` instead ;-)

Comment: @mosvy, you're right.

Comment: @iruvar but the idea in your answer is right: `awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1; i<ARGC; i++) vn+=(ARGV[i]~/^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*=/); print vn}' foo=bar zep=q too=r` => `3` (that pattern should catch assignment as they're described in /OPERANDS/argument/assignment [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_05))

Answer (score 1):

From [your comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475201/how-to-get-a-count-of-variables-passed-to-awk#comment868184_475201), it seems that you have an array in `bash` that you'd like to pass into an `awk` program on the command line.

Here's an easy way of doing that:

```
array=("my 1st item" "my 2nd item" "the last item")

(
    IFS=:

    awk -v var="${array[*]}" '
        BEGIN {
            array_len = split(var, array, ":")
            for (i = 1; i <= array_len; ++i)
                printf("Item #%d is \"%s\"\n", i, array[i])
        }'
)
```

This would output

```
Item #1 is "my 1st item"
Item #2 is "my 2nd item"
Item #3 is "the last item"
```

This takes the array and turns it into a single string of `:`-delimited items.  If any of the elements of the array contains `:`, then pick another character for delimiting the items in the string.  The expansion of `${array[*]}` will join the items in the array on the first character of `$IFS`, which is why we set this variable before performing that expansion. This string is passed to `awk` as the variable `var`.

In the `BEGIN` block in the `awk` program, we then create the array `array` and also keep track of the array's length in `array_len` through splitting `var` on `:`.  The loop is just for showing that we managed to split the string successfully.

We set `IFS` and run our `awk` program in a subshell so that the rest of the script can run with an unmodified `IFS` variable.

Comment: makes it easier, wondering putting it like this, wont show it in BEGIN,  awk  'BEGIN{print args}{}' args="${header[*]}" /tmp/enc1.txt  whereas this works well awk -v args="${header[*]}" 'BEGIN{print args}{}' /tmp/enc1.txt

Comment: @Bharat That first code won't work because `awk` will not have looked at the command line arguments (which are usually the names of files to parse) until _after_ the `BEGIN` block.

Comment: thanks, looks like ARGC and ARGV has that capability only

Answer (score 0):

Now, as `awk` doesn't provide means to get at its own command line and the options therein, this is a bit far fetched, and it relies on linux internals like the `proc` file system, but just for the fun of it (YMMV):

```
awk -v"VAR1=sd" -va=b -vJ=onny '
BEGIN   {("tr \47\\000\\n\47 \47\t\47 </proc/$PPID/cmdline") | getline CMDLN
         n = split (CMDLN, ELM, "\t")
         for (i=1; i<=n; i++)   if (sub ("^-v", "", ELM[i]))    {split (ELM[i], T, "=")
                                                                 print "Option", T[1], "=", T[2]
                                                                 Options++
                                                                } 
        }
'
Option VAR1 = sd
Option a = b
Option J = onny
```

The "command" being read by `getline` will be executed in a subshell, so we get at the cmdline of the parent PID, and `tr` the `<NUL>` and `<LF>` chars to `<TAB>`s. Then, the CMDLN is `split` into its elements, in each of which a leading "-v" is matched (and eliminated) to find variable definitions. Those are printed, and the options count incremented.
Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your array into awk directly with here-string.

```
awk -F'SEP' '{ print NF }' <<<"${header[*]}"
```

Where the `SEP` is the character which your array elements are delimited with.

Tset:

```
$ array=( 1, 2, 3, 7 )
$ awk -F',' '{ print NF }' <<<"${array[*]}"
4
```

And `$1` will be your first element's value, `$2` second and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a bash array, and bash knows how many elements are in the array, simply tell awk directly:

```
$ array=("my 1st item" "my 2nd item" "the last item")
$ awk -v var="${array[*]}" -v nargs=${#array[@]} '
  BEGIN {
    print nargs;
  }
'
3
```